# Why am I getting a syntax error in a previously tested code at "__kernel void smth(.."?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I used this code from another example in StackOverflow instead of my own code. Both give out the same syntax mistake at void

```
__kernel void SAXPY (__global float* x, __global float* y, float a)
{
    const int i = get_global_id (0);

    y [i] += a * x [i];
}
```

Maybe I forgot a library?

error message:

```
  File "<ipython-input-8-fb3ca4aa5029>", line 1
    __kernel void SAXPY (__global float* x, __global float* y, float a)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please add **exact error message** to the question post. And replace "kernel" with something more suitable: According to the [description of the kernel tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kernel/info), the tag is about an Operating System's kernel, and you question has definitely different nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks like OpenCL -- it isn't Python code, and won't run in a Python shell.